# Incorrect hostname in terminal after factory reset

Tags: macbook-pro, mojave, hosts

I wiped out Mac and reinstalled (Mojave) (logout from Cloud, Messages, deauthorized iTunes, erase disk, reinstall). Now my terminal is showing a name that I set up through Preferences -> Sharing on previous instance of  system (before reinstall).

I checked Preferences -> Sharing computer Name is:
Kathy’s MacBook Pro

When I check in bash:

```
red-panda:~ kathy$ scutil --get ComputerName
Kathy’s MacBook Pro
red-panda:~ kathy$ scutil --get LocalHostName
Kathys-MacBook-Pro
red-panda:~ kathy$ scutil --get HostName
HostName: not set
```

My questions:
1. Why red-panda is still there after reinstallation? Where that information is stored? If I want to sell the Mac, how can I be sure to wipe all out?
2. Can `HostName: not set` make any troubles?

Comment: In the erase step, did you erase from the running OS or from internet recovery or an external USB boot device? https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201065

Comment: From Mac OS recovery.

Comment: Wow, you’re right to be suspicious. I always enable file vault and the erase without entering the passcode. Feels better to get FileVault on as soon as I can and then blow away everything right before selling. Note macOS recovery can be a recovery partition on your previous system so your host name would move through in that case as opposed to internet recovery.

Comment: I haven't dumped NVRAM lately, perhaps a name or setting persists there?

Comment: <shrug> So whatever DHCPd you're using is assigning you an address that reverses to that name.  It's not a big deal.

Answer (score 2):

### 1.) `red-panda` is your current computer name.

1. Click Apple Menu on Top Left
2. Open the **System Preferences...** App
3. Type `Computer Name` in Search
4. Change the `red-panda` to whatever you like, I would suggest something short, like `KM`, if you plan to use Terminal a lot
5. Close **System Preferences...** App

---

### To securely wipe your hard drive, do an after-restart system reinstall and pick the proper option.

For more info and useful tips on how not to lose your own data before doing it, read some articles like this:

- [What to do before you sell, give away, or trade in your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201065)
- [How to reset your Mac before selling it](https://www.imore.com/how-to-prepare-mac-for-sale)

---

### 2. No, no trouble for no hostname. The hostname is not set by default upon install.

However, if you wish to set it, execute: `scutil --set HostName desired-hostname-here-again-I-suggest-a-short-name-like-kmp` in Terminal.

Comment: By my understanding my computer name is Kathy’s MacBook Pro (in System Preferences) AND red-panda - showed in terminal.

I reinstalled it step by step with link that bmike attached: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201065

Comment: In System Preferences... > Sharing > Click Edit Button. Is `Use dynamic global hostname` option checked?

Comment: Hm, no it's not. I think that's by default.

Comment: Yes, try to check it, and see if something is somehow set there. (It should not be)

Comment: Also, Have you tried to execute something like: `scutil --set HostName kmp` in the Terminal?

Comment: So I unchecked and checked and after restart it changed and now matches computer name. Thanks @Lucifer Morningstar. Can you explain why such behaviour in simple words (lets call me a newbie;))?

Comment: Kathy, usually such a behavior is caused by redundant path in the ((in this case) system) code, that uses a different route to do the same thing.

Comment: So if you have a method/function/procedure... called resetComputerName, this should be called every time that people want to reset the computer name. However, it is not so easy to be consistent in large systems. So sometimes there may be a different method/function/procedure... called resetCompName that somebody wrote not knowing about the first one, or an overloaded version that takes more/less/different parameters, or somebody just decides to manipulate some system variables directly, instead of bothering to see if there is already something that does it...

Comment: Sorry, this is not a small topic - in fact the simplest explanation would be that nature currently increases its entropy... aka: chaos increases no matter how much we fight it - but fight we must :)